# Is it possible sccessing a subset of a WCF service operations

Tags: c#, .net, service, wcf

I have the following doubt:
Consider the following:

```
/* My service is formed by several subservices 
   (subfunctionalities). Here is functionality 1 */
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMySubService1 {
   [OperationContract]
   int MyOp11(string opnd);
   [OperationContract]
   int MyOp12(stirng opnd);
}

/* My service is formed by several subservices 
   (subfunctionalities). Here is functionality 2 */
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMySubService2 {
   [OperationContract]
   int MyOp21(string opnd);
   [OperationContract]
   int MyOp22(stirng opnd);
}

/* My service is formed by several subservices 
   (subfunctionalities). Here is functionality 3 */
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMySubService3 {
   [OperationContract]
   int MyOp31(string opnd);
   [OperationContract]
   int MyOp32(stirng opnd);
}
```

And the following:

```
/* My server will implement a complex great 
   service made of the previously introduced subservices. */
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService : IMySubService1, IMySubService2, IMySubService3 {
}
```

well, I will implement my service:

```
// Implementing the service
public class MyService : IMyService {
   ...
}
```

OK! Up until now, nothing strange!
My service will be hosted on a server and I am happy :)
The service is hosted (as example) on a svc file, but remember the service is `IMyService`.

Now let's get to the point:
In my client I would like to create a client in order to get access JUST TO A SUBSET of my service. Given that my service is the usion of three subservices, I would like to access only one subservice.

For example, my client is interested in `IMySubService1`
Can I do the following?

```
ServiceEndpoint httpEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(
   ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IMySubService1)), 
   new BasicHttpBinding(), 
   new EndpointAddress("http://tempuri.org/MyService.svc/ServiceCall")
   );
ChannelFactory<IMySubService1> channelFactory = 
   new ChannelFactory<IMySubService1>(httpEndpoint);

IMySubService1svc = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
/* Calling methods in IMySubService1 */
int i1 = svc.MyOp11("A string");
int i2 = svc.MyOp12("Another string");
int i3 = svc.MyOp11("And another string");
int i4 = svc.MyOp12("In the end a string");
int i5 = svc.MyOp11("The final string");
```

Is this possible???

Comment: Have you tried it? If it didn't work, what error did you get?

Comment: I am sorry, it is just a curiosity... I didn't try it :P

Comment: Well, just try it, it shouldn't take long :)

Comment: Yes, the point is that now I am abroad, I will come back in three days,,, just wanted to know this in advance, I have not much time to spend in front of a computer (without my dev tools) :(

Comment: Good Ques!! but it seems that it is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK!
Finally I tried it!

IT CAN BE DONE!!! Exactly in the same manner as I showed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, interesting. Off the top of my head it looks like it should work as along as the `ServiceContract` attribute's `Name` and `Namespace` properties are set on the smaller sub-contracts. The values should match whatever the service is expecting for the composed contract.